# Give a line number and get that line

Tags: python, python-3.x

A txt file contain several line

I want to get certain line when I give line number

```
1   bird
2   car
3   computer
4   mobile
5   bike
6   train
```

ex I give line number 5, and I get bike

Indeed, txt file is just raw data,it does not contain line number

Comment: Hi, can you please show the code you have already tried?

Comment: see also other linked questions in the duplicate I suggested

Comment: I think some question title is difficult to be found.
I have search some time,but i still loss it.

Comment: @kovac I don't agree with the downvotes (at least if they are only for the question being duplicate), but finding the duplicate was quite easy, for example google search `python read specific line` or `python read line by number` or `python read single line` will give you the duplicate in the top results. The search on stackoverflow itself is however much worse in coming up with matching duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this:

```
# open the file as read only
f = open('your_text_file.txt', "r")

#save it in a list
lines = f.readlines()

#close file to save memory
f.close()

#now you have all lines in a list, you just have to choose a number!

#returns input number as string
number = input("Line number: ")

#int to convert string to integer
#-1 because python arrays start at 0
print(number +" "+ lines[int(number)-1])
```